# Should I mention in my SOP about one of that of my relatives studying at the university inspired me to join the same university?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

My cousin is stuyding in a university and I wish to apply to the same. Will it help mentioning her in the SOP that she has inspired me to apply there? Our areas of interest are different (she is more inclined to telecommunication and I am to ML). Will I be looked on favourably because she is one of the top rankers there? I know nepotism doesn't work anywhere but will it help in some way at least?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this could not possibly help your application. (It could possibly hurt it, if the committee feels that your inappropriate statement of purpose reflects badly on you, though this is unlikely.)